# How to calculate grand total of total values using FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I am new to FetchXML but enjoying the experience thus far. I have a report I am working on and I would like to get a grand total. The grand total is meant to be a sum of the results of row totals.

[image]

I want to calculate the value of `XXXX`.

I used this to calculate the value of the row totals:

```
=((Len(ReportItems!Textbox4.Value)) + (Len(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value)) + (Len(ReportItems!Textbox8.Value)) + (Len(ReportItems!Textbox10.Value)))/3
```

and I attempted to use this to calculate the grand total but I keep getting an error stating I can aggregate functions can only be used on report items contained in page headers and footers

```
=SUM(ReportItems!Textbox22)
```

I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty simple.
You want to calculate total of column Total no of products.

First make values of your that column as Number i.e data type of that column as number May it be float integer or so on.

Once you do that when you right click on any cell under Total no of products,
You will get option as Total i.e Ssrs by default gives you option for Total if your column data type is number.  Here is the example link.

Look for adding Total to report

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hello, thank you for your feedback. I tried it already and it did not work. I believe it is because my row total is computed based on an expression.

Comment: Expression does not make any difference, is your column of number type, if your total for each row is interger use integer function in ssrs to convert explicitly to interger. Also do you get option of total once you right click any cell under your total no of products column??

Answer (score 0):

Yon can use `aggregate` in `FetchXML` as in SQL. this is the syntax:

```
string sumFetch= @" 
  <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
   <entity name='opportunity'> 
     <attribute name='estimatedvalue' alias='estimatedvalue_sum' aggregate='sum' /> 
   </entity> 
 </fetch>";

var sumResult = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(sumFetch));

foreach (var c in sumResult.Entities)
{
   decimal sum = ((Money)((AliasedValue)c["sumResult"]).Value).Value;
   System.Console.WriteLine("Sum of estimated value of all opportunities: " + sum );
}
```

Here is the documantion:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/use-fetchxml-aggregation